# Получение файла из командной строки python

Tags: python, pandas

Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужно передать файл в python скрипт из командной строки:

```
python script.py filename.xlsx
```

Как получить путь к файлу в script.py  для последующей обработки в pandas?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.argv

Comment: Спасибо, вопрос закрыт.

Comment: Рекомендую еще вот эту статью почитать: https://habr.com/ru/post/466999/ плюс еще про [typer](https://typer.tiangolo.com) (его на момент написания статьи на хабре еще не существовало). Я обычно использую click или typer (и не использую argparse)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[sys.argv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.argv) позволяет использовать параметры в строго определенном порядке, что не всегда очень удобно если нужно передавать больше одного параметра.

Существует встроенный модуль [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) для парсинга аргументов командной строки, который намного мощнее и гибче `sys.argv`.

Вот небольшой пример - `test1.py`:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Test [argparse] module')
parser.add_argument('--string-parameter', '-s', dest='str_param',
                    help='a string parameter')
parser.add_argument('--float-parameter', '-f', type=float,
                    help='a float parameter')
parser.add_argument('--integers', '-lst', type=int, nargs='+',
                    help='a list of integers')

args = parser.parse_args()
print(f"args.str_param: {args.str_param}")
print(f"args.float_parameter: {args.float_parameter}")
print(f"args.integers: {args.integers}, sum: {sum(args.integers)}")
```

Примеры запуска:

> python test1.py -h

```
usage: test1.py [-h] [--string-parameter STR_PARAM] [--float-parameter FLOAT_PARAMETER] [--integers INTEGERS [INTEGERS ...]]

Test [argparse] module

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  --string-parameter STR_PARAM, -s STR_PARAM
                        a string parameter
  --float-parameter FLOAT_PARAMETER, -f FLOAT_PARAMETER
                        a float parameter
  --integers INTEGERS [INTEGERS ...], -lst INTEGERS [INTEGERS ...]
                        a list of integers
```

> python test1.py -s "a short sentence" --float-parameter 3.1415 -lst 10
> 20 30

```
args.str_param: a short sentence
args.float_parameter: 3.1415
args.integers: [10, 20, 30], sum: 60
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ!